# How to simultaneously read and delete contents of file in C

Tags: c

I am doing file read using fread as in the code below. Please help me on how to immediately delete the contents of the files that i completed to read. So if I read one value, delete that value from file and do fclose. Later when i open the file, then the file should be having only two values left.
I dont know which function to use to delete. Please help me.
(Which ever content is read, should get deleted)

I am using the code below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{

int *p; 

p = malloc(sizeof(int));
p1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
p2 = malloc(sizeof(int));

*p = 5;
*p1 = 6;
*p2 = 7;
FILE *fp1 = fopen("sridhar.txt","w");
 fwrite(p,sizeof(int),1,fp1);
 fwrite(p1,sizeof(int),1,fp1);
 fwrite(p2,sizeof(int),1,fp1);
 fclose(fp1);

 printf("\n Value of p p1 p2 written into the file is :%d \n",*p,*p1,*p2);

int *q, *q1, *q2;
FILE *fp2 = fopen("sridhar.txt","r");

q = malloc(sizeof(int));
q1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
q2 = malloc(sizeof(int));


fread(q,sizeof(int),1,fp2);
fclose(fp2); // Delete Logic may come here

*fp2 = fopen("sridhar.txt","r");
fread(q1,sizeof(int),1,fp2);
fclose(fp2);
// Delete Logic In here

*fp2 = fopen("sridhar.txt","r");
fread(q2,sizeof(int),1,fp2);
fclose(fp2);
// Delete logic here 

 printf("\n Value of q q1 q2 read from the file is :%d %d %d\n",*q, *q1,     *q2);

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The question is: what counts as _delete_ for you. Is it enough to overwrite it with blanks or zero-bytes? Or does it have to be removed completely, i.e. subsequent content is shifted (which is much more tedious).

Comment: Unrelated, but `int *q; q = malloc(sizeof(int));.. . fread(q,...` is pointless. Use `int q;... fread(&q,...` instead.

Comment: ...and `*fp2 = fopen("sridhar.txt","r");` should be `fp2 = fopen("sridhar.txt","r");`. Compile with all warnings enabled.

Comment: Yes, I need to shift the content to the top of the file and make file smaller as i read data. That is my requirement as of now. Can you please help me with a way of doing that.

Comment: Useful as a queue file is, not many common file systems support it natively:(

Answer (score 0):

There is no *delete* operation on basic files. You can read/write but not delete. Delete is a *logical* operation that you must implement by yourself even by marking in some way a record as *deleted* or moving the remaining part of the file on top of what you want to *delete*...

Note that there is no *insert* operation at all, there is too much semantic for *delete* and *insert* that modern file system don't provide one for you, you must build one by yourself (or use a library for this, or a structured access layer like a database...).